# Why does decreasing the size of the renderer offset my click events - How do I fix this

Tags: javascript, three.js

Currently my rendered model (grey in color) takes the whole width of the html page with my mesh in the center of that width. My aim is to decrease that width  - however by doing that the click even on the model seems to offset and Three.js still thinks that my mesh is still in the center of the width when in reality its not and has moved to the left as the width has decreased.

Code Example:

I currently have something like this the first step involves creating a renderer this places the rendered object that occupies the width of the screen and the rendered object in the center of that width. This code example works great

```
  var WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
  HEIGHT = window.innerHeight/2;

  // Create a renderer and add it to the DOM.
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
  renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
```

I am then pasting that rendered image into a div on my html page.

```
  container = document.getElementById( 'canvas' );
  document.body.appendChild( container );
  container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```

I then create a mesh and add that to an array called `targetList`

```
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    mesh.position = new THREE.Vector3(0, -3, 0) ;

    projector = new THREE.Projector();  
    document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );

    scene.add(mesh);
    targetList.push(mesh);
```

Now incase someone clicks on the rendered image the following function is called

```
function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) 
{
   console.log("Click.");
   // update the mouse variable
   mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
   mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

   // find intersections
   var vector = new THREE.Vector3( mouse.x, mouse.y, 1 );
   projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );
   var ray = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );

   // create an array containing all objects in the scene with which the ray   intersects
  var intersects = ray.intersectObjects( targetList );

  // if there is one (or more) intersections
  if ( intersects.length > 0 )
  {
      console.log("Hit @ " + toString( intersects[0].point ) );
  }

}
```

Now this all works fine and whenever i click inside the rendered model I get something like this which is great

```
Hit @ [ -0.12506098558617107, 2.650102060480923, 1.2154427674550532 ]
```

**Start of the problem**

Now the problem starts if I decrease the width and change the first statement

```
var WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
```

to 
    var WIDTH = window.innerWidth/2;

now when I click in the image I simply get "click" output and for some reason 3js thinks I did not click on the model. If i click in the center (the old position of the model) 3js thinks that i clicked inside the model. My question is why does decreasing the width as a result of which my model moved to the left of the screen have an affect on the cordinates. Why does 3js still think my model is in the center ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you change the width and height of render, the window size doesn't change. so when you unproject mouse, you should consider about this. "update mouse variable" operation will be `mouse.x = ( event.clientX / (window.innerWidth/2) ) * 2 - 1;
 mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / (window.innerHeight/2) ) * 2 + 1;`

Comment: it's helpful to check the reference also to understand what exactly is being returned by [window.innerWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth) and [event.clientX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent)